# From where can I get Landsat 7 and Landsat 8 metadata files?

Tags: metadata, landsat-8, landsat-7

I downloaded satellite images but mtl files were not in the zip. I searched a lot but i dint get from where to download mtl files. I need to convert radiance to temperature in both L7 and L8 images.

Comment: Can you specifiy from where you downloaded the data that it was provided without the Metadata files?

Comment: from earthexplorer. The file format is in jpg but no mtl file.I dont know whether you need special privileges as a user to download it.

Comment: To convert radiances to temperatures you'll need the full Level 1 dataset - "Level 1 GeoTIFF Data Product". These are distributed as GeoTiffs and allways contain the metadata in a MTL file. There are no special requirements, apart from registering a free account.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The USGS provides a tool for bulk downloading of Landsat Metadata:
[Landsat Bulk Metadata Service](http://landsat.usgs.gov/consumer.php)

The MTL files will allways be distributed with the data if you download the scenes through [USGS EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/).

If you don't want to download the bands again and just the MTL text files for each scene you can take a look at [Amazons Landsat Mirror](http://aws.amazon.com/de/public-data-sets/landsat/). Each scene is in a subfolder also containing a MTL text file with the metadata.

edit:

Landsat 8 metadata specifically is also released daily in [CSV format by USGS](http://landsat.usgs.gov/metadata_service/bulk_metadata_files/LANDSAT_8.csv) and can be queried with tools like [landsat-api](https://github.com/developmentseed/landsat-api).